# Add rows between datetime range

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a SQL (Sql Server) table that looks like this using :

```
SELECT *
FROM STOP
WHERE Start >= '01/01/2021 00:00:00' AND End <= '01/01/2021 23:59:59'
```

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 00:10:00 | 01/01/2021 00:45:00 |
| 01/01/2021 05:20:00 | 01/01/2021 05:40:00 |
| 01/01/2021 07:30:00 | 01/01/2021 07:32:00 |
| 01/01/2021 14:10:00 | 01/01/2021 15:00:00 |
| 01/01/2021 21:48:00 | 01/01/2021 22:30:00 |

But I need this result :

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 00:00:00 | 01/01/2021 00:09:59 |
| 01/01/2021 00:10:00 | 01/01/2021 00:45:00 |
| 01/01/2021 00:45:01 | 01/01/2021 05:19:59 |
| 01/01/2021 05:20:00 | 01/01/2021 05:40:00 |
| 01/01/2021 05:40:01 | 01/01/2021 07:29:59 |
| 01/01/2021 07:30:00 | 01/01/2021 07:32:00 |
| 01/01/2021 07:32:01 | 01/01/2021 14:09:59 |
| 01/01/2021 14:10:00 | 01/01/2021 15:00:00 |
| 01/01/2021 15:00:01 | 01/01/2021 21:47:59 |
| 01/01/2021 21:48:00 | 01/01/2021 22:30:00 |
| 01/01/2021 22:30:01 | 01/01/2021 23:59:59 |

My result should always start at dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00 and end at dd/mm/yyyy 23:59:59.

**How can I add row between my result to have a complete day ?**

Also, sometimes, Start Date begin on date X and End Date end on date X+1.

Comment: Rats - deleted in error. `Start >= '01/01/2021 00:00:00' AND End <= '01/01/2021 00:00:00'` Read that again - that will select no rows at all. Edit - i see now that your problem is more complex - taking a given day, applying the existing periods and then "filling in periods for everything else that is not covered by an actual row in the table for a given date. Is that correct?

Comment: Inclusive upper boundaries are a logic problem depending on how you intend to use this information and how much precision you need. datetime and datetime2 datatypes are/can be more precise. Think carefully about how you intend to use this information.

Comment: I have corrected my post. Thank you. -  taking a given day, applying the existing periods and then "filling in periods for everything else that is not covered by an actual row in the table for a given date. Is that correct? – Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each period you can use `LEAD()` to find out when the next period starts, so for your sample data:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, [Start] DATETIME, [End] DATETIME)
INSERT @T (Start, [End])
VALUES
    ('01/01/2021 00:10:00', '01/01/2021 00:45:00'),
    ('01/01/2021 05:20:00', '01/01/2021 05:40:00'),
    ('01/01/2021 07:30:00', '01/01/2021 07:32:00'),
    ('01/01/2021 14:10:00', '01/01/2021 15:00:00'),
    ('01/01/2021 21:48:00', '01/01/2021 22:30:00');

SELECT  Start, 
        [End],
        NextStart = ISNULL(LEAD(Start) OVER(ORDER BY Start), DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, Start)))
FROM    @T;
```

You would get an output as follows:

| Start | End | NextStart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:10:00.000 | 2021-01-01 00:45:00.000 | 2021-01-01 05:20:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 05:20:00.000 | 2021-01-01 05:40:00.000 | 2021-01-01 07:30:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 07:30:00.000 | 2021-01-01 07:32:00.000 | 2021-01-01 14:10:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 14:10:00.000 | 2021-01-01 15:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 21:48:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 21:48:00.000 | 2021-01-01 22:30:00.000 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00.000 |

This basically defines your existing periods (Start:End) then your gap to the next period (End:NextStart). You can then use `CROSS APPLY` to split this into two rows:

```
SELECT  x.start, x.[End]
FROM    (   SELECT  Start, 
                    [End],
                    NextStart = ISNULL(LEAD(Start) OVER(ORDER BY Start), DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, Start)))
            FROM    @T
        ) AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  t.Start, t.[End]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  t.[End], t.NextStart
            WHERE   t.NextStart <> t.[End] -- If Next Start = End then ignore as there is no missing period
        ) AS x
ORDER BY x.Start, x.[End];
```

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:10:00.000 | 2021-01-01 00:45:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:00.000 | 2021-01-01 05:20:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 05:20:00.000 | 2021-01-01 05:40:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 05:40:00.000 | 2021-01-01 07:30:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 07:30:00.000 | 2021-01-01 07:32:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 07:32:00.000 | 2021-01-01 14:10:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 14:10:00.000 | 2021-01-01 15:00:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 15:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 21:48:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 21:48:00.000 | 2021-01-01 22:30:00.000 |
| 2021-01-01 22:30:00.000 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00.000 |

Finally, you need fill in the missing period at the start, which you can do by identifying the first period using `ROW_NUMBER()` then adding a 3rd section to your cross apply:

```
SELECT  x.*
FROM    (   SELECT  Start, 
                    [End],
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Start),
                    NextStart = ISNULL(LEAD(Start) OVER(ORDER BY Start), DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, Start)))
            FROM    @T
        ) AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  t.Start, t.[End]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  t.[End], t.NextStart
            WHERE   t.NextStart <> t.[End]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  CONVERT(DATE, Start), t.Start
            WHERE   RowNumber = 1
        ) AS x
ORDER BY x.start, x.[End]
```

**[Example on db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70f2cc328cbecdca6bd6770207be82aa)**

If you want to make your ranges non-continuous, then you can deduct a second (or whatever your smallest unit is) from the end time, but I personally wouldn't bother. It is easier to work with continuous ranges and just change your use of operators (i.e. `<` instead of `<=`) then you don't have to worry about precision of types.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using range queries in MS SQL server on DateTime columns, there is no way you could do that using >= and <= (or using BETWEEN). Upper boundary should be exclusive. Also your DateTime literals are ambiguous. While for 01/01/2021 it is obvious it means Jan 1st, 2021, it wouldn't be clear what you meant for say, '01/02/2021'. Server would interpret it depending on its date settings. So you always should use a format that is not ambiguous plus doesn't get affected by the server language:

Having said that, you should write the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM STOP
WHERE Start >= '20210101' AND End < '20210102';
```

SQL server sensitivity is 3 milliseconds and this would tell to include all the rows on Jan 1st,2021 (00:00:00 is implicit when only date part is written). Note that for the end we are saying, it should be before Jan 2nd, 2021, and that would also cover anything up to but not including Jan 2nd 2021 00:00:00. Keep in mind that, the value is internally stored as a number and resolves to a value which has milliseconds part too for datetime.